# Words being cut off/running off in PDF using html2pdf

Tags: php, html, html2pdf

[image]

I tried to use truncate css.

```
.no-wrap{
text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width:1px;
}
```

but not working. For any help.Thanks, in advance.

Comment: there are no spaces so it wont wrap, the css support on any html to pdf is not great